# Does $G/\mathbb{T}=H$ implies that $G=\mathbb{T}\oplus H$?

Tags: topological-groups, exact-sequence

Let $G,H$ be two compact abelian groups, let $\mathbb{T}$ be the torus (also known as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ or $S^1$).

I have the following exact sequence
$$
1\rightarrow \mathbb{T} \rightarrow G \rightarrow H \rightarrow 1
$$
Can I conclude that $ G=\mathbb{T}\oplus H$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Yes:* The category of compact abelian groups is equivalent to the opposite of the category of abelian groups via the character functor $G\mapsto \widehat{G}:=\text{Hom}(G,T)$ (see [Pontryagin duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality)), and $T$ corresponds to $\widehat{T}\cong{\mathbb Z}$ under this equivalence. As the latter is projective in the category of abelian groups, the dual exact sequence $$0\to \widehat{H}\to\widehat{G}\to\widehat{T}\to 0$$ splits. In particular, we have $\widehat{G}\cong\widehat{T}\oplus\widehat{H}\cong\widehat{T\oplus H}$, hence $G\cong T\oplus H$, too.

Comment: You're welcome! Note however https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103972/the-injectivity-of-torus-in-the-category-of-abelian-lie-groups